# How I can avoid in OpenGL disappearing lines using a shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So I'm drawing some lines by just using a fragment shader. The vertex it's just an empty quad.

The issue I have is that when I zoom out the camera and the lines get smaller they sometimes appear and disappear and I don't understand why.

This is how it looks without zooming

[image]

and this is how it looks when the camera is far away from them

[image]

The more far away I get from them the more artefacts appear.

This is how my vertex shader looks

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 _position;

out vec2 position;

uniform mat4 uCameraView;

void main() {
  gl_Position = uCameraView * vec4(_position.x, _position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  position = _position;
}
```

And this is the fragment

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 position;

uniform vec4 uGridColor;
uniform float uTileSize;
uniform float uGridBorderSize;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
  vec2 uv = mod(position, uTileSize);
  vec2 border = mod(uv + (uGridBorderSize / 2.0), uTileSize);
  border -= mod(uv - (uGridBorderSize / 2.0), uTileSize);

  if (length(border) > uTileSize - uGridBorderSize) {
    fragColor = uGridColor;
  } else {
    fragColor = vec4(0.0);
  }
}
```

Why it's this happening? maybe is something related to antialiasing? My OpenGL setup it's just the default one.

Comment: what you want is some kind of antialiasing.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: Can we have a look at the C++ code? It's abit hard to tell from first glance, but it might be clearer with the full codebase.

Comment: my bet is you need to have constant line width (regardless of zoom) right now you got problems while un-zooming that the line will be less than pixel thick which sometimes result in invisible lines due aliasing effects (visible and invisible is function of position). The image of yours shows your lines have +/-1 different thickness its the same thing .... apply that to your check ... how is questionable as we do not know what variable is what and with what value,range etc. You should also pass view resolution in pixels as it would be needed for this...

Comment: The reason lines disappear is because they become smaller than a pixel. What would you like to happen in that case? Thare are usually two approaches to that: 1) don't allow the line thickness to be smaller to 1 pixel, 2) if the line is thiner than 1 pixel lerp with the background color. So in your case, when the line becomes smaller then 1 pixel, would become grey

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is making a binary decision "yes line" / "no line". However beyond a certain point (line width < pixel width) you're effectivly dealing with spatial frequencies above the Nyquist limit.

Instead of using a binary "yes"/"no" you need to calculate the pixel coverage, i.e. how much line is inside a pixel. For that you'd normally use a unsigned distance function (UDF). Here's some GLSL code for UDF lines in pixel space (you can also use them in normalized space, but then you'll have to adjust the smoothstep parameters). Try this on https://shadertoy.com

```
float lsd(vec2 a, vec2 b, vec2 p, float w){
    w *= 0.5;
    vec2  n = normalize(b-a);
    float l = length(b-a);
    float t = dot((p-a),n);
    float d = length((a-p)+t*n);
    float e = min(length(p-a)+w, length(p-b)+w);
    return (t > w && t < l-w) ? d : e;
}

float line(vec2 a, vec2 b, float width, vec2 fragcoord){
    return max(0., 1.-smoothstep(0., 1., lsd(a, b, fragcoord, width)-0.5*width));
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    float l =
          line(vec2(8.,8.), vec2(128.,33.), 1., fragCoord)
        + line(vec2(33.,220.), vec2(260.,20.), 4., fragCoord);
    fragColor = vec4(l,l,l,1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell based on your shaders alone, so here is an example of how to zoom and pan around a line grid. It uses a projection matrix to zoom which looks slightly different to how you implemented the zoom, but the important bit is that it doesn't have any artefacts of lines thinning when zooming/panning.

Here is a demonstration, hopefully the GIF shows it, but the grid lines are constant thickness as you zoom in and out:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

using std::vector;
using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec3;
using glm::vec4;

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

vec3 rayCast(double xpos, double ypos, mat4 projection, mat4 view) {
    // converts a position from the 2d xpos, ypos to a normalized 3d direction
    float x = (2.0f * xpos) / SCR_WIDTH - 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * ypos) / SCR_HEIGHT;
    float z = 1.0f;
    vec3 ray_nds = vec3(x, y, z);
    vec4 ray_clip = vec4(ray_nds.x, ray_nds.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // eye space to clip we would multiply by projection so
    // clip space to eye space is the inverse projection
    vec4 ray_eye = inverse(projection) * ray_clip;
    // convert point to forwards
    ray_eye = vec4(ray_eye.x, ray_eye.y, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    // world space to eye space is usually multiply by view so
    // eye space to world space is inverse view
    vec4 inv_ray_wor = (inverse(view) * ray_eye);
    vec3 ray_wor = vec3(inv_ray_wor.x, inv_ray_wor.y, inv_ray_wor.z);
    ray_wor = normalize(ray_wor);
    return ray_wor;
}

class Line {
    int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    vector<float> vertices;
    vec3 startPoint;
    vec3 endPoint;
    mat4 MVP;
    vec3 lineColor;
public:
    Line(vec3 start, vec3 end) {

        startPoint = start;
        endPoint = end;
        lineColor = vec3(1,1,1);

        const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
            "uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = MVP * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
            "}\0";
        const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
            "uniform vec3 color;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n"
            "}\n\0";

        // vertex shader
        int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        // fragment shader
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        // link shaders
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        // check for linking errors
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        vertices = {
             start.x, start.y, start.z,
             end.x, end.y, end.z,

        };
        
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
        glBindVertexArray(0); 

    }

    int setMVP(mat4 mvp) {
        MVP = mvp;
    }

    int setColor(vec3 color) {
        lineColor = color;
    }

    int draw() {
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
        glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "color"), 1, &lineColor[0]);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
        return 0;
    }

    ~Line() {
        // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    }
};

vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 15.0f);
vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0,0,-1);
mat4 model = mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 view;
glm::mat4 projection;
float scrollSpeed = 2.0f;
float fov = 45.0f;

int main()
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "grid", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Line x(vec3(0,0,0), vec3(1,0,0));
    x.setColor(vec3(1,0,0));
    Line y(vec3(0,0,0), vec3(0,1,0));
    y.setColor(vec3(0,1,0));

    std::vector<Line*> grid = {};
    for (int i = -5; i < 6; i++) {
        grid.push_back(new Line(vec3(-5, i, 0), vec3(5,i, 0)));
    }
    for (int j = -5; j < 6; j++) {
        grid.push_back(new Line(vec3(j, -5, 0), vec3(j,5, 0)));
    };

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos,  cameraPos + cameraFront, vec3(0,1,0));

        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
            grid[i]->setMVP(projection * view * model);
            grid[i]->draw();
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
        delete grid.at(i);
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}


void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{

    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; 

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;


    int state = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
    if (state == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
        cameraPos -= scrollSpeed * glm::vec3(xoffset/(float)SCR_WIDTH, yoffset/(float)SCR_WIDTH, 0);

    } else {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
        firstMouse = true;
    }
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    cameraPos += (float)yoffset * rayCast(lastX, lastY, projection, view);
}
```