# Drawing a colored grid with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, occupancy-map

My goal is to be able to create what is called an Occupancy grid, its similar to a tile/grid game, looks like the attached image. This is for a small robot project I am working on. All being done in C/C++.

So I want to be able to:

1. Change the resolution, or size of each grid cell. So for example 1x1cm or a 5x5cm, etc.
2. Change the color of each cell based on some criteria. Obstacle == black, free == white, etc. Might add user click on cell and it change color. For example if the robot starts in 0x0 the cell is red, then the next instance it moves to 1x1. Now 0x0 should be white color, and 1x1 should be red.
3. Add some form of scrolling or following (probably done through MVP camera).

What OpenGL method/approach should I take? I am currently thinking of:

1. Having a square shader (two triangle vertices and index buffer) with a color attribute. Then have a vertex array object/buffer with all the indicies and colors, but wondering how to handle changing colors during run time.
2. Having all the real world center or corner coordinates(0x0, 0x1, ...1x1, etc) for each grid and have the shaders draw the individual squares, if possible.
3. Use a texture/image of NxN and update the texture pixel colors.

I am just not sure what is the best scalable, or performant approach. What if I want to draw a 10000x10000 grid cell (zoom out far for example), or if the color is changing a lot.

The most dynamic aspect of the grid is the fill color. For example I may have a grid of 100x100. At one instance all cells are white, then as the robot moves I change the color of the corresponding cell. Or if it detects an obstacle in a cell change that cell color.

[image]

Comment: render single textured quad ... where the texture holds your colors... the grid lines can be done in fragment detecting fragment position is near multiple of grid size coordinate

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65713558/9238288) is an implementation of a grid. You can find a basic quad tutorial (first one on learnopengl.com) and then you will want to snap to the places between the grid lines when (and where) you click.  You can pass the color to the quad shader as a uniform.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with something that you should use for your project. It is a zoomable grid that can be resized to whatever dimensions you need. It should be relatively fast, lines are batched and quads are instanced. It has basic interaction with left and right click and the scroll wheel click and scroll, but you should be able to adapt this interface to your needs. The API should be fairly easy to use `createCell`, `removeCell`, etc...

A few things:

- The app doesn't render cells that are not in the view frustum, so performance is better when zoomed in, although there are some hacks to get this to work reasonably fast at zoomed out too
- I could only test to 1000x1000 squares (~10-12fps fully zoomed out), i didn't have enough memory for 10000x10000 squares (uses ~3GB).

This was fun to make and I hope you can make use of it, if you have any questions let me know!

*EDIT:*
yes the `flatten` section was a bit unstructured. That flatten method was originally just to flatten a 2D models vector down to a 1D vector to be sent to the GPU (the internal `_model` data). The ternary operations are determining a 2D slice of this list (think a box section within the main grid), which is how the frustum cull occurs.
bottomLeft and topRight is used to calculate the bounding box of the camera frustum which gets intersected with the whole grid to get indexes into an (ordered) vector of models and colors that gets sent to the GPU, its abit hacky but it ensures operations that interact with the grid (add, remove, change color,etc...) are O(1).
There was a small bug causing some cells to freeze, and it was caused by resetting the cell to uninitialized in the QuadRenderer's `remove()` method omitted it from being sent to the GPU (a performance saving optimization), and it was causing the memory to be offset incorrectly, and causing the rendering to desynchronize. So it could have been solved two ways, remove the check to send only initialized cells to the GPU (slower) or just set squares to white instead (hackier). So I chose to set removed cells to white, which means they still get rendered (even though they are camouflage with the clear color). You might be able to change so white cells don't get rendered either, but it shouldn't be too much lost performance, considering you keep cells uninitialized to start (don't for god sake initialize them to white! :) )

The remove() function can be changed to:

```
void remove(vec2 pos) { 

    //change color to white 
    colors[(int)pos.x][(int)pos.y] = vec3(1); 

}
```

[image: demo]

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec2;
using glm::vec3;
using glm::vec4;
using glm::perspective;
using glm::radians;
using glm::normalize;

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// grid dimensions
const unsigned int GRID_WIDTH = 1000;
const unsigned int GRID_HEIGHT = 1000;

float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;
bool realTimeUpdating = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

// TO DO a simple camera class
vec3 cameraPos = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 cameraFront = vec3(0,0,-1);
vec3 cameraRight = vec3(1,0,0);
vec3 cameraUp = vec3(0,1,0);
mat4 model = mat4(1.0);
mat4 view;
mat4 projection;
float scrollSpeed = 2.0f;
float fov = 90.0f;
float nearDist = 0.1f;
float farDist = 1000.0f;
float ar = (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT;

class LineRenderer {
    int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    mat4 viewProjection;

    vector<float> vertices;
public:
    LineRenderer() {

        const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
            "uniform mat4 viewProjection;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = viewProjection * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
            "}\0";
        const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
            "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);\n"
            "}\n\0";

        // vertex shader
        int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // fragment shader
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // link shaders
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        // check for linking errors
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        vector<float> placeHolderVertices = {
        };

        vertices.insert( vertices.end(), placeHolderVertices.begin(), placeHolderVertices.end() );
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
        glBindVertexArray(0); 

    }

    void setCamera(mat4 cameraMatrix) {
        viewProjection = cameraMatrix;
    }

    void addLine(vec3 start, vec3 end) {
        vector<float> lineVertices = {
             start.x, start.y, start.z,
             end.x, end.y, end.z,

        };

        vertices.insert( vertices.end(), lineVertices.begin(), lineVertices.end() );
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    int draw() {
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "viewProjection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &viewProjection[0][0]);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vertices.size() / 3);
        return 0;
    }
};

// maths functions to pick which grid (not necessary, just for demonstration purposes)

vec3 rayCast(double xpos, double ypos, mat4 projection, mat4 view) {
    // converts a position from the 2d xpos, ypos to a normalized 3d direction
    float x = (2.0f * xpos) / SCR_WIDTH - 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * ypos) / SCR_HEIGHT;
    float z = 1.0f;
    vec3 ray_nds = vec3(x, y, z);
    vec4 ray_clip = vec4(ray_nds.x, ray_nds.y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // eye space to clip we would multiply by projection so
    // clip space to eye space is the inverse projection
    vec4 ray_eye = inverse(projection) * ray_clip;
    // convert point to forwards
    ray_eye = vec4(ray_eye.x, ray_eye.y, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    // world space to eye space is usually multiply by view so
    // eye space to world space is inverse view
    vec4 inv_ray_wor = (inverse(view) * ray_eye);
    vec3 ray_wor = vec3(inv_ray_wor.x, inv_ray_wor.y, inv_ray_wor.z);
    ray_wor = normalize(ray_wor);
    return ray_wor;
}

vec3 rayPlaneIntersection(vec3 ray_position, vec3 ray_direction, vec3 plane_normal, vec3 plane_position) {
    float d = dot(plane_normal, plane_position - ray_position) / (0.001+dot(ray_direction, plane_normal));
    return ray_position + ray_direction * d;
}

template<typename T>
vector<T> flatten(const vector<vector<T>> &orig, vec2 bottomLeft=vec2(0,0), vec2 topRight=vec2(GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT))
{   
    vector<T> ret;
    // for(const auto &v: orig)
    //     ret.insert(ret.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
    float rx = (topRight.x >= GRID_WIDTH ? GRID_WIDTH : topRight.x+1);
    float ry = (topRight.y >= GRID_HEIGHT ? GRID_HEIGHT : topRight.y+1);

    float lx = (bottomLeft.x <= 0 ? 0 : bottomLeft.x);
    float ly = (bottomLeft.y <= 0 ? 0 : bottomLeft.y);

    for(int i = lx; i < rx; i++) {
        vector<T> v = orig[i];
        ret.insert(ret.end(), v.begin()+ly, v.begin() + ry);                                                                                          
    }
    return ret;
}   

class QuadRenderer {

public:

    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;

    unsigned int matrixBuffer;
    unsigned int colorBuffer;

    vector<vector<vec3>> colors;
    vector<vector<vec3>> frustumCulledColors;   
    vector<vec3> _colors;

    vector<vector<mat4>> models;
    vector<vector<mat4>> frustumCulledModels;
    vector<mat4> _models;

    mat4 viewProjection;

    vec2 bottomLeft=vec2(0,0);
    vec2 topRight=vec2(GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT);

    QuadRenderer() {

        // create an empty grid
        colors.resize(GRID_WIDTH);
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; j++) {
            colors[j].resize(GRID_HEIGHT);
            std::fill(colors[j].begin(),colors[j].end(),vec3(0));
        }

        models.resize(GRID_WIDTH);
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; j++) {
            models[j].resize(GRID_HEIGHT);
            std::fill(models[j].begin(),models[j].end(),mat4(0));
        }

        const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "layout (location = 1) in mat4 aInstanceMatrix;\n"
        "layout (location = 5) in vec3 aCol\n;"
        "uniform mat4 viewProjection;\n"
        "out vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = viewProjection * aInstanceMatrix * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
        "   color = aCol;\n"
        "}\0";
    const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "in vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(color,1);\n"
        "}\n\0";

        // build and compile our shader program
        // ------------------------------------
        // vertex shader
        unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // fragment shader
        unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        // check for shader compile errors
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        // link shaders
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        // check for linking errors
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
        }
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        float vertices[] = {
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // top right
             1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
             0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
             0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f   // top left 
        };

        unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
            0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
            1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
        };

        _models = flatten(models);
        _colors = flatten(colors);

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &matrixBuffer);
        glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);

        // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, matrixBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _models.size() * sizeof(mat4), &_models.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // set attribute pointers for matrix (4 times vec4)

        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(mat4), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(mat4), (void*)(sizeof(vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


        glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(mat4), (void*)(2 * sizeof(vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

        glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(mat4), (void*)(3 * sizeof(vec4)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);

        glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _colors.size() * sizeof(vec3), &_colors.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(5, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
        glBindVertexArray(0); 
    }

    void calculateFrustum() {
        vec3 rayWorld = rayCast(0, SCR_HEIGHT, projection, view);
        vec3 worldPos = rayPlaneIntersection(cameraPos, rayWorld, vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,0));
        bottomLeft = vec2((int)worldPos.x, (int)worldPos.y);

        rayWorld = rayCast(SCR_WIDTH, 0, projection, view);
        worldPos = rayPlaneIntersection(cameraPos, rayWorld, vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,0));
        topRight = vec2((int)worldPos.x, (int)worldPos.y);
    }

    // send updated data to GPU
    void update() {
        _models = flatten(models, bottomLeft, topRight);
        _colors = flatten(colors, bottomLeft, topRight);

        vector<mat4> shadedCellModels = {};
        vector<vec3> shadedCellColors = {};

        for (int i = 0; i < _models.size(); i++) {
            // only send initialized cells to the GPU
            if (_models[i] != mat4(0) && _colors[i] != vec3(0)) {
                shadedCellModels.push_back(_models[i]);
                shadedCellColors.push_back(_colors[i]);
            }
        }


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, matrixBuffer);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, shadedCellModels.size() * sizeof(mat4), &shadedCellModels.front());

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, shadedCellColors.size() * sizeof(vec3), &shadedCellColors.front());
    }

    void addQuad(vec2 pos, vec3 col) {

        mat4 model = translate(mat4(1.0), vec3(pos, 0.0));
        models[(int)pos.x][(int)pos.y] = model;
        colors[(int)pos.x][(int)pos.y] = col;
    }

    void remove(vec2 pos) {
        //change color to white
        colors[(int)pos.x][(int)pos.y] = vec3(1);
    }

    void setCamera(mat4 cameraMatrix) {
        viewProjection = cameraMatrix;
    }

    void draw() {

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "viewProjection"), 1, GL_FALSE, &viewProjection[0][0]);

        // render quad
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, _models.size()); 
        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

};

vec3 selectedColor = vec3(0,1,0);
bool leftMouseButtonPressed = false;
bool rightMouseButtonPressed = false;

class Grid {
public:

    LineRenderer lines;
    QuadRenderer cells;

    Grid() {

        //glLineWidth(2);

        // draw horizontal lines of grid
        for (int j = 0; j <= GRID_HEIGHT; j++) {
            lines.addLine(vec3(0, j, 0), vec3(GRID_WIDTH, j, 0));
        }
        // draw vertical lines of grid
        for (int i = 0; i <= GRID_WIDTH; i++) {
            lines.addLine(vec3(i, 0, 0), vec3(i,GRID_HEIGHT, 0));
        };

    }

    void addCell(vec2 gridPos, vec3 color, bool updateImmediately=true) {

        // ignore mouse clicks outside the grid
        if (gridPos.x < 0 || gridPos.x > (GRID_WIDTH -1) || gridPos.y < 0 || gridPos.y > (GRID_HEIGHT -1)) {
            return;
        }
        cells.addQuad(gridPos, color);  
        if (updateImmediately) {
            cells.update();
        }
    }

    void removeCell(vec2 gridPos, bool updateImmediately=true) {

        // ignore mouse clicks outside the grid
        if (gridPos.x < 0 || gridPos.x > (GRID_WIDTH -1) || gridPos.y < 0 || gridPos.y > (GRID_HEIGHT -1)) {
            return;
        }
        cells.remove(gridPos);
        if (updateImmediately) {
            cells.update();
        }
    }

    void draw() {

        cells.draw();
        lines.draw(); 
    }
};

Grid *grid;

int main()
{

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "grid", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_button_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    grid = new Grid();
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_WIDTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_HEIGHT; j++) {
            // when setting up grid have updateImmediately=false
            // and batch update once at the end
            grid->addCell(vec2(i,j), vec3(1,0,0), false);
        }
    }
    // batch update
    grid->cells.update();


    // point camera at center of the grid, 15 units back from the grid
    cameraPos = vec3(GRID_WIDTH/2, GRID_HEIGHT/2, 15.0f);

    projection = perspective(radians(fov), ar, nearDist, farDist);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // set camera
    view = lookAt(cameraPos,  cameraPos + cameraFront, vec3(0,1,0));
    grid->cells.setCamera(projection * view);
    grid->lines.setCamera(projection * view);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        // float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        // deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        // lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // std::cout << "FPS: " << 1.0/(0.00000001+deltaTime) << std::endl;
        processInput(window);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        grid->draw();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    delete grid;

    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    // ray cast to find quad underneath mouse cursor

    if (leftMouseButtonPressed) {
        // cast from camera through mouse position
        vec3 rayWorld = rayCast(lastX, lastY, projection, view);
        // check for intersection with grid
        vec3 worldPos = rayPlaneIntersection(cameraPos, rayWorld, vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,0));

        vec2 gridPos = vec2((int)worldPos.x, (int)worldPos.y);

        grid->addCell(gridPos, selectedColor);
    } 
    if (rightMouseButtonPressed) {

        // cast from camera through mouse position
        vec3 rayWorld = rayCast(lastX, lastY, projection, view);
        // check for intersection with grid
        vec3 worldPos = rayPlaneIntersection(cameraPos, rayWorld, vec3(0,0,1), vec3(0,0,0));

        vec2 gridPos = vec2((int)worldPos.x, (int)worldPos.y);

        grid->removeCell(gridPos);
    }

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_1) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(1,0,0);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_2) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(0,1,0);    
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_3) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(0,0,1);    
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_4) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(1,1,0);  
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_5) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(1,0,1);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_6) == GLFW_PRESS)
        selectedColor = vec3(1,1,0);       
}


void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{

    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; 

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    // switch to update less frequently when many squares on the screen
    if (cameraPos.z > 15.0f) {
        realTimeUpdating=false;
    } else {
        realTimeUpdating=true;
    }

    // scrolling moves camera closer and further from the grid
    int state = glfwGetMouseButton(window, GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE);
    if (state == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
        cameraPos -= scrollSpeed * vec3(xoffset/(float)SCR_WIDTH, yoffset/(float)SCR_WIDTH, 0);
        // update camera
        view = lookAt(cameraPos,  cameraPos + cameraFront, vec3(0,1,0));
        grid->cells.setCamera(projection * view);
        grid->lines.setCamera(projection * view);
        grid->cells.calculateFrustum();

        if (realTimeUpdating) {
            grid->cells.update();
        }
    } else {
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
        firstMouse = true;
    }
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    scrollSpeed = cameraPos.z * 0.1;
    cameraPos += (float)yoffset * scrollSpeed * rayCast(lastX, lastY, projection, view);
    // update camera
    view = lookAt(cameraPos,  cameraPos + cameraFront, vec3(0,1,0));
    grid->cells.setCamera(projection * view);
    grid->lines.setCamera(projection * view);
    grid->cells.calculateFrustum();
    grid->cells.update();
}

void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{

    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        leftMouseButtonPressed = true;
    } else {
        leftMouseButtonPressed = false;
    }

    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        rightMouseButtonPressed = true;
    } else {
        rightMouseButtonPressed = false;
    }

    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
        if (!realTimeUpdating) {
            grid->cells.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is amazing! I dont know how to give you more points for this. This will go a long way to my end state goal, gave me a solid foundation. Cant thank you enough

Comment: I am a little confused on what your `flatten` method is doing

Comment: I see now, there was a bug. I have fixed the code.