# Draw multiple lines using OpenGL 3.0+ in C

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 2d

My goal is to display multiple straight lines using [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/) 3.0 or newer in C. I want the window to look something like the following.

[image: Window with lines]

### Deprecated way

This is how I would do it using OpenGL 2.0, but I want to achieve this with newer versions of OpenGL.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(10, 10);
    glVertex2f(20, 20);
glEnd();
```

### Create window

This code creates a simple window using OpenGL. Now I want to draw multiple lines inside that window, which are defined with absolute coordinates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        fputs("Failed to initialize GLFW\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Example", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fputs("Failed to initialize GLEW\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Do you in general know how to draw geometry in a core profile? Because this would require a major tutorial to explain. Basically, you need a shader, a vertex array object, a vertex buffer object and wire that together. Lines work the same as any other geometry (you with two vertices instead of three). I'd start with [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/), and when you come up with a specific problem, ask about it here.

Comment: Your best bet might be to try and convert [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069424/9238288) C++ line drawing code to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to draw a `line` given two `vec2`s that are specified in screen coordinates:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

typedef struct vec2 {
    float x;
    float y;
} vec2;

vec2* vec2_init(float _x, float _y) {
    vec2 *v = (vec2*)malloc(sizeof(vec2));
    v->x = _x;
    v->y = _y;
    return v;
}

typedef struct vec3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} vec3;

vec3* vec3_init(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    vec3 *v = (vec3*)malloc(sizeof(vec3));
    v->x = _x;
    v->y = _y;
    v->z = _z;
    return v;
}

typedef struct line {
    int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    float *vertices;
    vec2 *startPoint;
    vec2 *endPoint;
    vec3 *lineColor;
} line;

line* line_init(vec2 *start, vec2 *end) {

    line *l = (line*)malloc(sizeof(line));

    float x1 = start->x;
    float y1 = start->y;
    float x2 = end->x;
    float y2 = end->y;
    float w = SCR_WIDTH;
    float h = SCR_HEIGHT;
 
    // convert 3d world space position 2d screen space position
    x1 = 2*x1 / w - 1;
    y1 = 2*y1 / h - 1;
 
    x2 = 2*x2 / w - 1;
    y2 = 2*y2 / h - 1;
 
    start->x = x1;
    start->y = y1;
    end->x = x2;
    end->y = y2;

    l->startPoint = start;
    l->endPoint = end;
    l->lineColor = vec3_init(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
        "}\0";
    const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "uniform vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\n\0";

    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // link shaders
    l->shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(l->shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(l->shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(l->shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // setting vertex data
    l->vertices = (float*)(malloc(sizeof(float) * 6));
    l->vertices[0] = start->x;
    l->vertices[1] = start->y;
    l->vertices[2] = end->x;
    l->vertices[3] = end->y;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &l->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &l->VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(l->VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, l->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(l->vertices)*4,
                                  &l->vertices[0],
                                  GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                            2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
    glBindVertexArray(0); 

    return l;
}

int line_draw(line *l) {

    glUseProgram(l->shaderProgram);
    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation(l->shaderProgram, "color"),
                                          1, &l->lineColor->x);

    glBindVertexArray(l->VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        fputs("Failed to initialize GLFW\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Example",0,0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fputs("Failed to initialize GLEW\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    line *line1 = line_init(vec2_init(100,100), vec2_init(100,200));
    line *line2 = line_init(vec2_init(200,100), vec2_init(400,150));
    line *line3 = line_init(vec2_init(400,600), vec2_init(600,400));
    line *line4 = line_init(vec2_init(300,300), vec2_init(500,100));
    line *line5 = line_init(vec2_init(600,50) , vec2_init(400,100));
    line *line6 = line_init(vec2_init(400,400), vec2_init(800,600));

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1);

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 
        line_draw(line1);
        line_draw(line2);
        line_draw(line3);
        line_draw(line4);
        line_draw(line5);
        line_draw(line6);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Result:

[image: draw lines]

**Note**: This isn't necessarily the fastest way to draw multiple lines (see: [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67585643/9238288)), but it should get you started on how it is done in the shader pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with how openGL graphics pipeline works, there are lots of tutorials on internet and I would suggest you read up on them instead(personally I like learnopengl.com). If you do know how it works and you are not sure how to generate vertices and indices here example for drawing a line:
First you need to generate vertices, so if you want line
from A(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0) to B(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0) you would pass this data to vertex buffer:

```
float data[] = 
{
    0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0
};
```

pass with:

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

but before that you need to generate and bind a vertex buffer and a vertex array, am not gonna go through it, because there is already lots of better explained info on internet.

also you will probably need to pass indices buffer to vertex array, indices is used to tell openGL in what order to draw lines, so if you have two 3D points, A and B, indices to draw a line with them would be:

```
float indices[]
{
   0, 1
};
```

you should imagine indices as something that connects a line together, 0 and 1 connects point A to point B if you had third point C, indices would be:

```
float indices[]
{
   0, 1, 1, 2
};
```

you might be wondering, why not 0, 1, 2. it's because we are drawing two separate lines, line from A to B and line from B to C.
0, 1, 2 would be a triangle (if you draw using GL_TRIANGLES).

also you might ask, why not pass this lines using only vertices without using indices array, so from A to B to C would be:

```
float data[] = 
{
  0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0,  //Duplicate

  1, 0, 0,  //Duplicate
  1, 1, 0
};
```

And you can do that, but it's not recommended, since you need to pass duplicate data which is a waste, espacially with more complex models than a line, it's fine in case of a line.